# Keep QMainWindow minimized when QDialogs show()

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I have an application with `QMainWindow` as the UI which is in minimized state, after some time the application throws a message by calling `messageDlg->show()` (`messageDlg` is a `QDialog` object). Something like this

```
void MainWindow::WarningDialog() 
{
    m_messageDialog = new QDialog(this);
    m_messageDialog ->show();
}
```

This results in my `QMainWindow` in normal mode which I don't want to happen i.e. am trying to keep the application in minimized window even if any `QDialog.show()` is called.

I don't want the keep checking if the application in minimized mode every time a `QDialog->show()` is called.

I've tracked all events posted to `QMainWindow::event()` but the only event I see happening before restoring my window is a `QEvent::WindowStateChange` i.e. the window state has already changed from minimized mode.

Is there a way to keep the `QMainWindow` minimized even if any `QDialog`s are shown?

Comment: while `QDialog` is running, set `QMainWindow` to `minimized` force.
Seems, your `QDialog` is modal.

Comment: no, its not modal. hmm, I don't think there's a minimized "force" for QWidget

Answer (score 1):

`QWidget` has slot `showMinimized()`. You should create `QDialog` without parent as `QMainWindow`. In your `QDialog` set attribute (e.g.

```
 QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;
 dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

), then you can set `showMinimized()` for `QMainWindow` in time when your `QDialog` had start.

Comment: hmm..If the mainwindow is not the parent of QDialog then the mainwindow would stay minimized anyways and the dialog would appear as a floating window by itself in the middle of the screen irrespective of the mainwindow, which is clearly not a good way of showing application messages to user. For the dialog to appear in an appropriate location we would want the mainwindow as the parent

Comment: Your `QDialog` should be modal dialog. Else, you can't do it.
Yet, dirty hack: `hide()` your `QMainWindow` instead minimized.

Comment: I created simple program, what it demonstrate that you need (with `hide()` `QMainWindow`). If you want, i can send it.

Comment: so u r suggesting to hide() QMainWindow when dialog pops up and setminimized() when dialog closes?

Comment: sure, can you post it on ideone.com or pastebin?