# Keep QDialog open when parent is minimized?

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, qdialog

I have a `QMainWindow` opening a `QDialog` (not modal). When I minimize the main window, the dialog is closed as well. Can I somehow keep it open? (the other way round as in [Keep QMainWindow minimized when QDialogs show()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630980/356726) ).

One thing I have tried is to `ignore` the event, but to my surprise I never see such a state. Actually I only see `ActivationChange (0n99)` there.

```
    void CMyDialog::changeEvent(QEvent *evt)
    {
        QEvent::Type t = evt->type();
        if (t == QEvent::WindowStateChange)
        {
            evt->ignore();
            hide();
        }
        else
        {
            QDialog::changeEvent(evt);
        }
    }
```

Question in Qt center dealing with a similar topic:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24765-Intercept-minimize-window-event

---

Here I create it as member:

```
QScopedPointer<MyDialog> m_navigator{new MyDialog(this)}; // this here is the main application window
```

It is displayed by a public slot:

```
void MyDialog::toogleNavigator()
{
   this->setVisible(!this->isVisible());
}
```

and is a `QDialog` derived class:

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog { ...
```

---- Edit 2 ------

First Wouter has mentioned it , then Alexander. It is like you guys say, if I pass **no** parent (as in Alexander`s minimal example), the dialog stays open - with parent it is minimized along with its parent. My apologizes Wouter.

However, in my case it does not work like that. So I did not turn Wouter`s comment without checking or in bad intention. Now it is my duty to find out why. I suspect some utility classes to alter the dialog. I will report back here when I have found the root cause.

Ok, it is the windows flags. If the dialog is a tool window, it is always minimized, as normal window it depends on the parent.

Comment: Can't you open the QDialog without parent?

Comment: Nope, it does not. Have tried. Qt 5.5, Win10. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create and open the dialog?

Comment: I stand there correcedt @Wouter, see edit 2 above. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create MyDialog without **this**(MainApplication) like parent
and may be play with a second parameter of the constructor.

```
new MyDialog(0/*, ?*/);
```

**Addition** It is working code

MainWindow.cpp

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QScopedPointer<Dialog> dialog;
};
```

MainWindow.hpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    dialog(new Dialog(0))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    dialog->setVisible(!dialog->isVisible());
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately removing the parent pointer does not do the trick, it was already discussed above.

Comment: Just to crosscheck, I run Qt 5.5 on Win 10, your environment?

Comment: Qt 5.5.0 MinGW 32 / Win 7 Pro

Comment: OK, will check the minimal example of yours and report back (as soon as I have time) - thx.

Comment: Thanks for insisting on "that it is working". Your minimal examples works at my place as well, see EDIT 2 above.